# Linking Price Set to new event

Tags: civievent, price-sets

I must have missed this step, I have the price set all updated but it I cannot find where to link to this years new event.  I appreciate your help.  tj

Comment: pls tell us what you have tried so we don't tell you stuff you have already done.

Comment: have you gone to Manage Events, found the Event, clicked on Configure and then to Fees and set the Price Set there?

Comment: I actually had been there many times, finally I checked the box "Yes" Is it a Paid Event, and then the choice came up for me to choose the price set.  Holy frustrating - but figured it out, thank you for advising I try it one more time.  Thank you Mr Life Saver

Comment: I will add as an answer - SE likes this - pls accept.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Manage Events

Find the Event

Click on Configure and then to Fees and set the Price Set there